# <aura:iteration> and input or <lightning:checkboxGroup>

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, javascript, controller, checkbox

I have a custom object `Topics__c` that I want list out like so:

[image]

The text is the topic name which is a String data type. So I have to add in a checkbox along side the Name field. I have been doing some research and it looks like `<lightning:checkboxGroup>` is the way to go with groups of checkboxes. My only hang up is I am not sure how to bind the topic to the checked item and pass that value to the controller.

This is what I have so far:

```
<aura:component implements ="force:lightningQuickAction, force:hasRecordId" controller="EditMeetingReport">
   <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
   <aura:attribute name="selectedTopics" type="List[]"/>
   <aura:attribute name="topicList" type="List[]" default="topicList" />


   <lightning:recordEditForm recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                          objectApiName="Meeting_Report__c"
                          onsuccess="{!c.onSuccess}"
                          onerror="{!c.onError}"
                          onsubmit="{!c.onSubmit}"
                          aura:id = "editMeetingReportForm">
   <lightning:messages />
   <lightning:inputField fieldName="Name" />
   <lightning:inputField fieldName="Date__c" />
   <lightning:checkboxGroup aura:id="checkbox"
                             name="Checkbox Group"
                             label="Add Topics"
                             options="{! v.topicList }"
                             value="{! v.selectedTopics }"/>
<lightning:button type="submit" name="save" label="Update" class="slds-button_brand"/>
```

JS Controller

```
doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
    var recordId = component.get("v.recordId");
    var action = component.get("c.getTopicList");
    action.setCallback(this, function(result){
        var state = result.getState();
        if (component.isValid() && state === "SUCCESS"){
            component.set("v.topicList", result.getReturnValue());
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
},
onSubmit : function(component, event, helper) {
    var inputCmp = component.find("checkbox");
    var value = inputCmp.get("v.selectedTopics");
    console.log('inputCmp: ' + inputCmp); //not giving me the right output
    var selectedTopics = component.get("v.selectedTopics");
    console.log('selectedTopics: ' + selectedTopics); //not giving me the right output
},
```

Should I be using `<aura:iteration>` and `<lightning:input>` instead because I am using two different objects in one table?

**How do I get the selected Topic's saved into the `selectedTopics` list?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data type for the attribute is incorrect. It should be `List`, not `List[]` (which means a List of Lists). I'd also recommend setting a default (empty) list:

```
<aura:attribute name="selectedTopics" type="List" default="[]" />
```

Everything else should be fine.

Comment: thank you. I also found that the `topicList` is set as a list of the Topic__c object rather then like this: component.set("v.topicList", `[{ label: "Insurance", value: "a07S0000007dOIVIA2"}, { label: "WEISX", value: "a07S0000007dOIzIAM" }]);` Do you know if and why the format of the options attribute as to be set exactly like this format with the label and value? I believe this is the reason why I couldn't set the selectedTopics attribute. I am having trouble dynamically building the topic list in this exact format.

Comment: @Olivia options has to be in that format because that is how the code was written. The documentation is clear on this. To convert a record to an acceptable list of options, you can do this: `var options = records.map(record=>({label:record.Name,value:record.Id}));`

Comment: ah thank you so much, this was so helpful. One last question if you don't mind. what data type would `selectedTopics` be? When I pass the selectedTopics values to an apex class from the controller, I am passing it as a List<String> or a List<Sobject> but neither seem to be registering the values in the class.

Comment: @Olivia `List<String>` should work. Maybe it's how you're trying to pass them in? They should be an Array in JavaScript.